# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: increment is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, increment

I am working on a game that needs a number that will stop once it reaches a certain point. I have managed to do that so far. But, when I put it into the rest of my code it stopped working and I got this error: `VM1756:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: increment is not defined`. To start it type `upload trojan`.

```js
var l1 = document.getElementById('l1');
var l2 = document.getElementById('l2');
var l3 = document.getElementById('l3');
var l4 = document.getElementById('l4');
var l5 = document.getElementById('l5');
var l6 = document.getElementById('l6');
var l7 = document.getElementById('l7');
var l8 = document.getElementById('l8');
var l9 = document.getElementById('l9');
var l10 = document.getElementById('l10');
var l11 = document.getElementById('l11');
var l12 = document.getElementById('l12');
var l13 = document.getElementById('l13');
var l14 = document.getElementById('l14');
var l15 = document.getElementById('l15');
var l16 = document.getElementById('l16');

function runcmd() {
  var user = document.getElementById('code').value;
  if (user == 'upload trojan') {
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l1.innerHTML = "uploading trojan";
    }, 2000);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l2.innerHTML = "...";
    }, 1900);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l3.innerHTML = "Compression Complete.";
    }, 1800);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l4.innerHTML = "Authorized...";
    }, 17000);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l5.innerHTML = "Calculating Space Requirements";
    }, 16000);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l6.innerHTML = "Waiting for response...";
    }, 15000);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l7.innerHTML = "tar -xzf Texture";
    }, 1400);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l8.innerHTML = "Calculating Space Requirements";
    }, 1300);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l9.innerHTML = "Entering Security Console...";
    }, 1200);
    window.setInterval(function() {
      l10.innerHTML = "Authorized...";
    }, 1000);
    var a = 0;
    var b = 5;
    var c = 10;
    var d = 15;
    var e = 20;
    var f = 25;

    function increment() {
      if (a == 300) {
        // stop when it hits 300
        window.clearInterval(id);
        return;
      }
      a++;
      document.getElementById('l11').innerHTML = Number(a).toLocaleString('en');
      if (b == 80) {
        // stop when it hits 80
        window.clearInterval(id);
        return;
      }
      b = b + 5;
      document.getElementById('l12').innerHTML = Number(b).toLocaleString('en');
      if (c == 17) {
        // stop when it hits 80
        window.clearInterval(id);
        return;
      }
      c = c + 5;
      document.getElementById('l13').innerHTML = Number(c).toLocaleString('en');

      if (d == 123) {
        // stop when it hits 80
        window.clearInterval(id);
        return;
      }
      d = d + 5;
      document.getElementById('l14').innerHTML = Number(d).toLocaleString('en');
      if (e == 175) {
        // stop when it hits 80
        window.clearInterval(id);
        return;
      }
      e = e + 5;
      document.getElementById('l15').innerHTML = Number(e).toLocaleString('en');
      if (f == 970) {
        // stop when it hits 80
        window.clearInterval(id);
        return;
      }
      f = f + 5;
      document.getElementById('l16').innerHTML = Number(f).toLocaleString('en');
    };
    var id = window.setInterval('increment()', 100);
  };
};
```

```css
.span {
  color: #66ff33;
  font-family: "consola";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: #66ff33;
}
textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  color: #66ff33;
}
.console {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-left: 10px solid #cccccc;
  border-top: 5px solid #cccccc;
  border-right: 10px solid #cccccc;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #cccccc;
}
.exit {
  float: right;
  background: #800000;
  color: white;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="con" class="console">
  <button class="exit" onclick="hidecon()">X</button>
  <div>
    <span class="span" id="l1" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l2" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l3" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l4" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l5" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l6" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l7" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l8" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l9" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l10" style="width:50px"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="span" id="l11" style="width: 5px" value="0"></span><span class="span" id="l11" value="0" style="width: 5px"></span><span class="span" id="l12" value="0" style="width: 5px"></span><span class="span" id="l13" value="0" style="width: 5px"></span>
    <span
    class="span" id="l13" value="0" style="width: 5px"></span><span class="span" id="l14" value="0" style="width: 5px"></span><span class="span" id="l15" value="0" style="width: 5px"></span><span class="span" id="l16" value="0" style="width: 5px"></span>
      <span class="span" id="l17" style="width: 5px"></span>
  </div>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;color:#66ff33;">C:\></span>
  <input id="code" style="position: absolute; left: 30; bottom: 0; width:250px;border:2px solid white;background-color:black" />

</div>
<button style="border:none;position:absolute;background-color:black;bottom:0;left:114;color:#66ff33;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px solid white;" onclick="runcmd()">Send Command</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the many reasons for *not* using strings with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. If you use a string, the code is run at global scope, but your `increment` function doesn't exist at global scope (which is good).

Instead, just refer to it directly using its identifier:

```
var id = window.setInterval(increment, 100);
```